# Angular2 Typescript Conversion

Tags: typescript, angular

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

(function(app) {
  function MyController() {
    this.fname1 = 'RGFsdG9uDQo';
    this.lname1 = 'RGhhdmFyZXYNCg';
    this.addr1 = "UGFjaGFsYW0NCg";
  }
  MyController.prototype.get1 = function() {
    return "Addr: " + this.addr1;
  };
  app.directive("ch", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      transclude: true,
      bindToController: {
        fname1: '@',
        lname1: '=',
        update1: '&'
      },
      controller: MyController,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      template: ['<input ng-model="ctrl.fname1">',
        '<input ng-model="ctrl.lname1">',
        '<input ng-model="ctrl.addr1" ng-change="ctrl.update1({addr: ctrl.get1()})">'
      ].join('')
    };
  });
})(app);

(function(app) {
  function MyController() {
    this.fname2 = 'RGFsdG9uDQo';
    this.lname2 = 'RGhhdmFyZXYNCg';
    this.addr2 = "UGFjaGFsYW0NCg";
  }
  MyController.prototype.update2 = function(addr) {
    this.addr2 = addr;
  };
  MyController.prototype.get2 = function() {
    return "FName: " + this.fname2;
  };
  app.directive("pr", function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {},
      transclude: true,
      bindToController: {},
      controller: MyController,
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      template: ['<input ng-model="ctrl.fname2">',
        '<input ng-model="ctrl.lname2">',
        '<input ng-model="ctrl.addr2">',
        '<br /><br />',
        '<ch fname1="{{ctrl.get2()}}" lname1="ctrl.lname2" update1="ctrl.update2(addr)"></ch>',
        '&#09;',
        '<ch fname1="{{ctrl.get2()}}" lname1="ctrl.lname2" update1="ctrl.update2(addr)"></ch>'
      ].join('')
    };
  });
})(app);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Angular 1</title>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
  <pr></pr>
</body>

</html>
```

> **How to convert [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/psdutar9/) to angular2 components in typescript language.**
>   **This is a sample code using bindToController.**
>   **There is a parent directive.**
>   **Under that, there are some other directives (their children).**
>   **It has scopes @, & and =.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't as simple as converting it. Angular 2 is an all new framework. The concepts are different and you'll build the apps differently.

Comment: I know. I just want to know how a parent component communicates with with it children in angular2. I this example parent and child communicates with each other. Also two children communicate with each other through their parent. There should be something similar in angular2

Answer (score 0):

I would create two components. One for your `ch` directive:

```
import {Component,Input,Output} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ch',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="fname1">
    <input [(ngModel)]="lname1">
    <input [(ngModel)]="addr1" (change)="update1()">
  `
})
export class ChComponent {
  @Input() fname1:string;
  @Input() lname1:string;
  @Input() addr1:string;
  @Output('update1') update1Event;

  constructor() {
    this.fname1 = 'RGFsdG9uDQo';
    this.lname1 = 'RGhhdmFyZXYNCg';
    this.addr1 = "UGFjaGFsYW0NCg";
    this.update1Event = new EventEmitter();
  }

  update1() {
    update1Event.emit(this.addr1);
  }
}
```

And one for your `pr` directive:

```
import {Component,Input,Output} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChComponent} from './ch.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'pr',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="fname2">
    <input [(ngModel)]="lname2">
    <input [(ngModel)]="addr2">
    <br /><br />
    <ch [fname1]="fname2" [lname1]="lname2" 
        (update1)="update2($event)"></ch>
    &#09;
    <ch [fname1]="fname2" [lname1]="lname2" 
        (update1)="update2($event)"></ch>
  `,
  directives: [ ChComponent ]
})
export class PrComponent {

  constructor() {
    this.fname2 = 'RGFsdG9uDQo';
    this.lname2 = 'RGhhdmFyZXYNCg';
    this.addr2 = "UGFjaGFsYW0NCg";
  }

  update2() {
    this.addr2 = this.addr2 + "1";
  }
}
```

**Edit**

Following your comment, here are more details:

- for @, you can use this syntax: . Name must be defined in the component with @Input.
- for =, you can use this syntax: . Name must be defined the same Wayne but isn't necessary or type string.
- there is no support of &. You need to leverage custom events with EventEmitter to do something similar.

Home it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I have updated the code to make it more clear.
Please update code so that 
fname1: '@',
lname1: '=',
update1: '&' with parameters passed

Comment: Ok. So there is no suuport for '&' in angular2

But what if I pass first name as follows
fname1="{{ctrl.get2()}}"

Also how to pass parameters using EventEmitter